# Azure directory authentication in Sharepoint App

Tags: sharepoint-2013, azure-web-app-service, azure-active-directory

I've being trying to fix this problem for a week without luck. I am trying to access a sharepoint application hosted on azure that has the option "Log in with Azure Active Directory" enabled on azure .The app works perfect in sharepoint withouth that option in azure, what am I doing wrong?

Also, consider that my app uses the rights Web amd User Profiles as "read", stated on AppManifes.xml. Like I said, the app works well when the "Log in with Azure Active Directory" option is not enabled.

Comment: Did "Log in with Azure Active Directory" option means that you set the **Authentication / Authorization** for the app service? And would you mind share the detail error you were handling?